# c++ pointer being freed was not allocated with a short example

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>

class base{
  public:
  base(){};
  base ( base& b ) {};
  virtual void run(){};
  ~base(){std::cout<<"destructor for base"<<std::endl;};
};

class derived : public base {
   int alpha;
   public:
   derived ( ): alpha (0), base() {};
   derived ( base& b ) : alpha(0), base(b) {};
   void run(){};
   int* get_address () { return &(this->alpha); };
   ~derived(){std::cout<<"destructor for derived"<<std::endl;};
};

void make_derived ( std::shared_ptr<base>& b ){
    b.reset ( new derived () );
}

int main(){
  std::shared_ptr<base> b;
  make_derived ( b ) ;
  std::shared_ptr<derived> d = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived> (b);

  std::shared_ptr<int> a ( d->get_address() );

  b->run();
}
```

I compiled this code and ran it. The error message is "pointer being freed was not allocated". This is a pretty common error message. I, however, don't understand why there appears anything freed. It dies immediately after `std::shared_ptr<int> a ( d->get_address() );`. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: `alpha` was only allocated as part of the entire `derived` object. The `derived` object should be deallocated, not its members.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Well.. then, I don't understand why `derived` gets deallocated

Comment: You shouldn't create a shared_ptr object based on the "address of" operator. i.e. d->get_address() is not valid for initializing a shared_ptr (nothing ever called "new int" ).

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<int> a ( d->get_address() );` doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to control the lifetime of something whose lifetime is already controlled by something else?

Answer (score 1):

Don't `delete` that which you did not `new`.  When you pass a pointer to a `shared_ptr` constructor or `reset` function, you are setting up a deferred call to `delete` on that pointer (assuming you don't also pass a custom deleter). That's what is happening here:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> a ( d->get_address() );
```

You're passing the address of an `int` to a `shared_ptr` constructor. But that `int` was not allocated with `new`, and so should not be handled by a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: So.. the simplest fix would be just using normal C++ pointer?

Comment: The simplest fix would be to delete that line entirely, since you're not doing anything with that pointer.

Comment: Well.. I am not doing anything only in this simplified example. I am doing something in my real program. Using normal pointer works fine. Thank you very much for this help.